# Webpack 2 Not Tree Shaking D3.js Properly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, webpack, ecmascript-6, tree-shaking

Webpack will include **all** of d3.js in the bundle when doing `import { select } from 'd3'` as seen in the following [bundle visualization.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHDS3.png) The problem can be solved by doing `import { select } from 'd3-selection'` but this defeats the purpose of automatic tree shaking somewhat.

Tree shaking does appear to work in simple cases on our non-library code.

We use `"modules": false` in our `.babelrc` in order to retain the module syntax and use `'module'` resolve in our webpack.config.js `resolve: { mainFields: ['module', 'browser', 'main'] }` in order to select d3's module based code. As you can see the imported [node_modules/d3/index.js](http://pastebin.com/rjsc4mps) is partitioned in ES6 modules instead of a monolithic browser bundle or CommonJS export.

Should this be posted as an issue on the webpack github page or am I doing something wrong? This is using all the latest versions of the libraries (`d3@4.5.0`, `webpack@2.2.1`, etc)

edit:
Seems like this is related to the following issues:

- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2867
- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2899

Comment: Just wanted to comment that I have run into the same issue with Webpack 2.2.1 and d3 4.6.0. Tree shaking does work for other libraries. Please comment if you have found any solution.

Comment: Looks like there is a new webpack plugin to handle Common JS. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: While the apparent bug is being fixed (if possible at all) I'd consider importing from a more specific module. E.g. `import {select} from 'd3-selection'`, or even `import select from 'd3-selection/src/select'`.

Answer (score 4):

Tree shaking will only work for ES6 modules because they can be statically analyzed. AMD/CommonJS which a lot of libs publish can't be, which is why you're probably not seeing any tree shaking happening. Please see https://advancedweb.hu/2017/02/07/treeshaking

UPDATE:
There appears to be a new webpack plugin that is capable of tree shaking Common JS modules, https://github.com/indutny/webpack-common-shake. Please note, that the repo says it's in alpha.